# resources for developing an mid-size java application

Tags: java, design-patterns, user-interface, architecture

so I have been through all the courses on programming, algorithms, etc. and did a lot of coding and some small projects.
Now, I may start working on a real project, real java SE program with gui and everything, not big, but much more complicated than average school project. My experience says that when I'm having more classes in my project (say 10), it kind of gets difficult to decide from where this constructor should be called, if I should pass this parameter here or create it later and **how the whole thing should work together.**

can you recommend me some resources on this? Should I go the way of studying the design patterns or how do I get to design apps that have nice architecture?
what is the procedure when developing an app with lots of classes and gui and so on?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns usually help in making an application more maintainable and also more flexible. Although which design patterns to use relies essentially on what type of problem you have.

I did go through [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book, which provided me with a quick and easy way to grasp what design patterns are and how they work.

Since you are dealing with GUI related applications, my only recommendation would be to try and make your GUI and Logic seperate. This should reduce clutter and should make your code more understandable since each class deals with items related to its layer (GIU or Logic).

Breaking things down also makes your application more flexible and reusable. [Cohesion vs Coupling](http://www.agile-code.com/blog/cohesion-vs-coupling-separate-concerns/) should also be another thing which you should keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For design patterns : [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) & [Design Patterns: Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

For Effective Programming Guidelines : Recommended reading [Joshua Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

I personally like to thing in a TDD approach and love to read this blog [Writing Testable Code by Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/).
It explains how should we focus on making code loosely coupled and testable.

And lastly keep exploring open source libraries and projects they will keep you up to date with latest trends and coding styles.

Answer (score 0):

Head first Design Patterns or even the original Design patterns book from the Gang of Four (if you are the kind of person who likes more direct theory) for application design and I think it may be useful for you to have some knowledge of enterprise design patterns (Enterprise Integration Patterns from Hohpe and Wolf) will help you to understand how to implement flexible communication even in small SE projects. (Even these systems needs sometimes some kind of interprocess communication).

Additionally, the answers of Narendra and npinti are very good advices as well.

Have fun!